# Diff directories with content in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, diff, netbeans6.8

I duplicated some folder with project's config to a new project a few days ago and made there some modifications (project name, paths, etc).
After few days a source config dir has changed and I am wondering how to diff that folders in 2 projects to apply that changes in new project.

If I select source file and then new file and select diff option in Netbeans - it works. But is it possible to make in on whole folder ?

Comment: Can you look at the new best answer, and possibly select it? I just tried it and it's perfect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was looking for folder compare in NetBeans too. I found http://kenai.com/projects/netbeans-dircomp/downloads. I'll try that in a little while...

Comment: And if this doesn't work for you, there's always diff -r <dir1> <dir2>

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: Now that kenai.com no longer exists, does anybody know if the plugin can be download from elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

NetBeans does not have that feature.

You could probably hack together a shell script that would do this, based on find, etc. This [search for 'diff a directory tree'](http://www.google.com/search?q=diff+a+directory+tree) looks like it has some good answer.

I would recommend that you put your source code under some sort of source code control system like CVS, SVN or Mercurial.

You could use those tools to generate a diff of the original project's config between the date you made the copy and 'now'... and then apply that diff onto the copy of the project...

Or, you could apply some of the strategies described in [CVS manual for handling third party sources](http://ximbiot.com/cvs/manual/cvs-1.11.23/cvs_13.html#SEC103).  I think the same concepts are available for svn and mercurial.

Comment: A work in progress, perhaps?  Here are 2 open bugs:
http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=188543
http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=189273
And a plugin:
http://kenai.com/projects/netbeans-dircomp
(At least for me on 7.2, that plugin correctly identifies changed files, BUT it fails/refuses to actually diff them.)

Comment: it looks like it can compare only files editable in IDE, so it works nice for sources and displays 'Not comparable' for other extensions.

Answer (score 1):

A very old question, but Netbeans does have a CVS feature now.

Go to Tools>Plugins and find CVS and install.

After that it is very easy to right click a directory, go to tools, then apply diff patch.  That will patch all files in the diff file in that directory.  Simple and smooth.

Answer (score 0):

And You Can Also Use The 
`Total Commander` 
to Compare the folder and all type off your files 
Its amazing in this situation